# Include ext4.h in C program

Tags: c, header, kernel

I'm trying to create a little program that can read the ext4 filesystem, and for that i need to use all the structures that are defined in the `ext4.h` file. 
Problem is, that this file includes a set of kernel headers such as

```
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>
#include <linux/jbd2.h>
#include <linux/quota.h>
#include <linux/rwsem.h>
#include <linux/rbtree.h>
#include <linux/seqlock.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
... and more
```

I've installed the kernel headers using:

```
$ apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

So now i have them in `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.../include` and i try to compile my program with `-I /path/to/kernel-headers` but now it seems that there're headers included in those headers that it can't find such as `asm/current.h` which in my filesystem is `asm-generic/current.h`

Do someone that ever did something like this can help me?

Comment: Headers of Linux kernel, located outside of `include/uapi`, usually are not suitable for inclusion in user space programs. And `ext4.h` header is not an exception. Moreover, this header is outside of `include/` so it is intended for none kernel code except ext4 driver. It seems you need to use other ready-maid header for get ext4 layout, or write your own header.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/). This is the user-space toolset for manipulating ext2/3/4 filesystems, and it contains a userspace [implementation of the filesystem](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/ext2fs) you can adapt.

Comment: Agree. I got that to build on Windows.

Comment: The Linux distros should also have development packages built from e2fsprogs sources. For example, Ubuntu / Debian-based distros have the libext2fs-dev package.